# azure grant third party subscription deploy permissions

Tags: azure, permissions, active-directory, user-controls, arm

I'm developing a cloud service and I would like clients to be able to grant my azure acount permissions to programatically deploy an application in their account.  Is there a way of doing this?

For security reasons, I don't want them to simply create a new account for me.  I know this can be done in AWS but having trouble finding out how to do it in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Active Directory to create an account or modify a current account.

They are give you permission to deploy across the subscription or they can give you contributor access to resource groups.